# IIS7 URL Rewrite rule to perform a 301 redirect from *.html files to *.php files

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I would like to use the URL Rewrite module of IIS7 to create 301 redirects based on a specific pattern.

I have a web site that consists of only .HTML files. I am converting the site to .PHP files, but keeping all of the same filenames. For example, the following urls...

```
/index.html
/contact/contact.html
/membership/member.html
```

will become...

```
/index.php
/contact/contact.php
/membership/member.php
```

Can anyone advise on how to create this rule?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="html2php" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.+)\.html$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}.php" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Tested on IIS 7.5 with URL Rewrite module v2.0 -- works fine.

Comment: still working on finishing the site. Will have it running within a few days and then I'll get the URL rewrite working. I'll let you know; I promise.