# ASP.NET Basic URL Rewriting or code in master page

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, master-pages

I'm updating my website and some of the URLs have changed and some been deleted. I would like to redirect people visiting the old URLs from search engines to the new URLs.

I can quite easily do this in my Master Page code or I believe I can use ASP.NET URL Rewriting but I haven't used URL rewriting before. Could someone suggest which route should I take?

If URL Rewriting is best in my scenario, please could someone provide a simple example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect your previous URLs to a new location just using your web.config file.

This is an example of redirecting a URL to another location in the Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rule name="redirect to sign-in" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="previous-folder/SignIn.aspx"/>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://newWebSite.com/SignIn.aspx" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On a related note, is there a simple way to rewrite the following example URL: `~/article.aspx?id=123` to something like: `~/article/article-title-here.aspx` or `~/article/article-title-here/`

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you use a 301 Permanent Redirect in these cases - which can be done with URL Rewriting or just the HTTP Redirect feature in IIS 7 - 8.  I think the benefit to using Rewriting in this case would be the fact that you could use regex search/replace or rewrite maps, as opposed to a hard-coded URL or folder structures.  My suggestion would be to use the HTTP Redirect module for a small number of URLs or URL Rewrite for a large number where you need more flexibility and programmability.

The 301 instructs the search engines that the URL has permanently changed, and it *should* not reduce your Page Rank, while also updating to the new URL in the future.

Here is a StackOverflow post about using the URL Rewrite module for 301's:

[URL Rewrite Maps (iis.com)](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module)

[URL Rewrite and 301 redirects (stackoverflow.com)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057639/iis7-url-rewrite-rule-to-perform-a-301-redirect-from-html-files-to-php-files)

With HTTP Redirect, I don't think you can do complex search/replacing like you can with URL Rewrite, but you can tell it to have everything under a certain URL, go to a different URL, or everything under a specific folder to go to another specific URL/folder.  Here is a screenshot of the HTTP Redirect module in inetmgr.exe:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer (+1) but I was really simple solution which @Ali's is.