# Custom url for different ActionResults?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am in the process of moving old website to a new ASP .Net MVC website. The old site has pretty bad url naming scheme. I would love to ignore the old ways and just create new urls, however, A LOT of links point to the old links for SEO. Therefore, I have to maintain the older url.

So let's say this is the old url:
web.com/items/products/Hello-World-Hyphens

How do I input that on MVC?

I got ProductsController:

```
ActionResult HelloWorldHyphens() { return View(); }
```

Which will output to web.com/products/HelloWorldHyphens

However, I need it written in the old ways. Starting with /items/ and having hyphens in controller name.

Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
[OutputUrl="/items/products/Hello-World-Hyphens"]
ActionResult HelloWorldHyphens()
```

Comment: which version of mvc?  mvc 5 has attribute routing which lets you do something like [Route("/items/products/Hello-World-Hyphens")]

Comment: FYI - You don't *have* to use the old URLs. For SEO purposes, you can use 301 (permanent) redirects to the new locations. You can either do that through the [IIS rewrite module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057639/iis7-url-rewrite-rule-to-perform-a-301-redirect-from-html-files-to-php-files) in web.config, or you can specify the 301 redirects in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are moving to a new ASP MVC website then you can take advantage of attribute routing in MVC 5.

If you add attribute routing when you register your routes:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then you can add routes on methods:

```
[Route("/items/products/Hello-World-Hyphens")]
ActionResult HelloWorldHyphens()
```

Comment: I decided to use this solution. Thanks